# Why PrefixMap ++ PrefixMap become mutable.Map

Tags: scala

Running a PrefixMap example of programming in Scala in sbt console.

```
scala> PrefixMap("abc" -> 12, "abb" -> 13)
res0: PrefixMap[Int] = Map(abc -> 12, abb -> 13)

scala> PrefixMap("aaa" -> 15)
res1: PrefixMap[Int] = Map(aaa -> 15)

scala> res0 ++ res1
res2: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(abc -> 12, abb -> 13, aaa -> 15)
```

This result confused me.

I've thought when "++" method is called, "++" method uses implicit canBuildFrom in object PrefixMap and new PrefixMap instance is created, but it seems to use another implicit value from somewhere and new Map instance is created.

Why is res2 type not PrefixMap?
Or, I made a mistake somewhere?

Following is a code from PrefixMap example.

```
import collection._
import scala.collection.mutable.{Builder, MapBuilder}
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

object PrefixMap {
  def empty[T] = new PrefixMap[T]

  def apply[T](kvs: (String, T)*): PrefixMap[T] = {
    val m: PrefixMap[T] = empty
    for (kv <- kvs)
      m += kv

    m
  }

  def newBuilder[T]: Builder[(String, T), PrefixMap[T]] =
    new MapBuilder[String, T, PrefixMap[T]](empty)

  implicit def canBuildFrom[T]
    : CanBuildFrom[PrefixMap[_], (String, T), PrefixMap[T]] =
      new CanBuildFrom[PrefixMap[_], (String, T), PrefixMap[T]] {
        def apply(from: PrefixMap[_]) = newBuilder[T]
        def apply() = newBuilder[T]
      }
}

class PrefixMap[T] extends mutable.Map[String, T]
  with mutable.MapLike[String, T, PrefixMap[T]] {
  var suffixes: immutable.Map[Char, PrefixMap[T]] = Map.empty
  var value: Option[T] = None

  def get(s: String): Option[T] =
    if(s.isEmpty) value
    else          suffixes get (s(0)) flatMap (_.get(s substring 1))

  def withPrefix(s: String): PrefixMap[T] = {
    if(s.isEmpty) this
    else {
      val leading = s(0)
      suffixes get leading match {
        case None => suffixes = suffixes + (leading -> empty)
        case _    =>
      }
      suffixes(leading) withPrefix (s substring 1)
    }
  }

  override def update(s: String, elem: T) =
    withPrefix(s).value = Some(elem)

  override def remove(s: String): Option[T] =
    if(s.isEmpty) { val prev = value; value = None; prev}
    else suffixes get (s(0)) flatMap (_.remove(s substring 1))

  def iterator: Iterator[(String, T)] =
    (for (v <- value.iterator) yield ("", v)) ++
      (for ((chr, m) <- suffixes.iterator;
            (s, v) <- m.iterator) yield (chr +: s, v))

  def += (kv: (String, T)): this.type = { update(kv._1, kv._2); this }
  def -= (s: String): this.type = { remove(s); this }

  override def empty = new PrefixMap[T]
}
```

Comment: `PrefixMap`s are `mutable.Map`s. It looks like it's considering it to be the common supertype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all it is important to understand that there is a difference between the type of a variable and the type of the value stored in that variable. In your example the actual type of the result `++` is still `PrefixMap` but the type of the variable (i.e. what the compilers can prove) is just `mutable.Map` and this is what you see in REPL. You can easily verify this by printing `res2.getClass` to get the actual type.

I think this happens because `Map` has actually two different `++` methods:

- one comes from `TraversabelLike` and it is a smart one with `CanBuildFrom` and all the other fancy stuff
- another comes from `scala.collection.MapLike` overridden at `scala.collection.mutable.MapLike` and it is much less generic

```scala
 // collection.MapLike so here Map is collection.Map
 def ++[V1 >: V](xs: GenTraversableOnce[(K, V1)]): Map[K, V1]

 // mutable.MapLike so here the output Map is the mutable.map
 override def ++[V1 >: V](xs: GenTraversableOnce[(K, V1)]): Map[K, V1]
```

Since your code is located in a specific context where compilers knows exactly the class (as opposed to something like a generic `.filter` which has to use `TraversableLike` infrastructure), the compilers uses the simpler `++` coming from `mutable.MapLike`.

I'm not sure why this other `MapLike.++` method exists in the first place. Probably this is to support backward compatibility with some legacy design (Scala collections library has been re-designed several times). But the only way to make this bunch of methods (there are several more like `+`) to work as you wish, is to do what `mutable.MapLike` does: i.e. override them in your `PrefixMap` defining more specific types. Also beware that `MapLike.++` internally uses `clone()`, so you better to work correctly with that or to re-implement it.

Comment: After reading your post, I verified whether `++` method calls `mutable.MapLike.++` or not. The result is certainly `++` method calls `mutable.MapLike.++` and not call `TraversableLike.++` method that has implicit `CanBuildFrom` parameter. Thanks for an answer.